# Apache2: client denied by server configuration: /www

Tags: 16.04, apache2, raspberrypi, apache2.4

I've seen a number of similar questions, but none for the `/www` folder - as such, none of the related questions seem to fix my problem.

When I try to access my website via localhost I get a 403 error, with the following error log:

```
[Wed May 10 11:41:10.930677 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 1113] [client 127.0.0.1:38380] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /www
```

Now, I believe my virtual host is setup correctly:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /www/var/bluespice
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ORNL_bluespice_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ORNL_bluespice_access.log combined
    <Directory /www/var/bluespice>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The only way I can get around this issue is to change the following part of the `apache2.conf` file:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But as I understand it, this is highly insecure, so I'd like to solve it in a safer manner.

I've also tried adding the following to `apache2.conf` without success:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Can anyone see where I might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose `DocumentRoot` must be `/var/www/bluespice` instead of `/www/var/bluespice`, because the default work directory (defined in `apache2.conf`) is `/vaw/www`.

Comment: Well, I've been stuck on this for like three days, and neither my manager or I spotted this... Thanks so much - such a dumb mistake! (I'll accept in 9 minutes when I can...)